# What is the solution set for point $X$ if $|AX|^2+ |BX|^2=c$?

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, locus

Let there be distinct points $A$ and $B$ and a given $c\gt0$. What is the solution set for point $X$ if $|AX|^2+ |BX|^2=c$?

I started solving this problem as:
$\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{AX}-\overrightarrow{BX}\implies(\overrightarrow{AB})^2=(\overrightarrow{AX}-\overrightarrow{BX})^2\implies|AB|^2=|AX|^2-2\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{BX}+|BX|^2 $
$\implies|AB|^2+2\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{BX}=|AX|^2+|BX|^2$

It is clear that $|AB|^2+2\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{BX}=c$

But from here on I am completely lost how to determine the solution set for point X.

SOS. I need serious help. Any tips?

Comment: One interesting case is when $c=|AB|^2$.

Comment: A hint: By an isometry you may pick coordinates so that $A$ and $B$ lies on the axis of the 1st  coordinate and even so that they lie symmetric with respect to the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of the line segment $AB$.  Show (e.g., using [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)) that
$$AX^2+BX^2=2MX^2+\frac{AB^2}{2}\,.$$
This result is known as [Apollonius's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem).

Thus, if $c>\dfrac{AB^2}{2}$, then the locus of the point $X$ is a circle centered at $M$ with radius $\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{2}-\dfrac{AB^2}{4}}$.  If $c=\dfrac{AB^2}{2}$, then $X=M$.  Otherwise, $X$ does not exist.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand the answer if $c>\dfrac{AB^2}{2}$? If I write this like this: $|MX|^2= \frac{c}{2}-\frac{1}{4}|AB|^2$ I get an equation for hyperbola. But you concluded it is a circle. How come?

Comment: @thunder  These are fixed: $c$, $M$, and $AB$.  The equation you got is the same as $$MX=\sqrt{\frac{c}{2}-\dfrac{AB^2}{4}}=:\rho\,,$$ where $\rho$ is a fixed quantity.  Therefore, $X$ is at a fixed distance $\rho$ from $M$.  Thus, $X$ is on the circle centered at $M$ with radius $\rho$.

Comment: Got it! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $z$, $a$ and $b$ to represent the points $X$, $A$ and $B$, respectively, in the complex plane. From the given $|AX|^2+ |BX|^2=c$, we have

$$(z-a)(\bar z - \bar a) + (z-b)(\bar z - \bar b )= c$$

or,

$$|z|^2 - \frac{a+b}2\bar z - \frac{\bar a+\bar b}2z = \frac{c-|a|^2-|b|^2}2$$

which is equivalent to

$$|z -  \frac{a+b}2|^2 = \frac{2c-|a-b|^2}4 = r^2$$

Thus, $|AX|^2+ |BX|^2=c$ represents a set on a circle with center $\frac{a+b}2$ and radius $r$ if $2c \ge |a-b|^2$; empty otherwise.